# ::before content is put inside a figcaption, is there any way to avoid this?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

An image is hidden by a gray box (with a number) the same size as the image. When hovering over, the gray fades and reveals the image, and after a while a text fades in on top of the image.

I began backwards, writing the fade-in for the text before I wrote the fade-out of the "box." However, the content of the box (the figure) is put inside the figcaption tag, and styled as its rule. Why does this happen, and is there a way around my problem?

Here are the relevant parts of the code.

```css
section figure {
  counter-increment: numImg;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

section figure::before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: counter(numImg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #0e533e;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

section figure:hover figcaption {
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

section figure figcaption {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px white;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://cheb-room.ru/uploads/cheb/2016/11/w9RC4W-QqXw-200x200.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>Text that should fade in</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

The only thing I've found so far is that opacity affects everything in a container (that is, in figcaption), but not any way to avoid my counter to show up *in* the figcaption.

Comment: Can you explain your problem again? Is it that you don't want the counter to show up until after the image is revealed? Or that the image isn't being revealed on hover? I"m not sure the exact problem you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could tell, the pseudo before object was not appearing inside the figcaption element, but inside the figure element as expected. I added a hover state for the before element to fade it out at the same time as your text, so it appears to be behaving as you want it to.

```css
section figure {
  counter-increment: numImg;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

section figure:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: counter(numImg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #0e533e;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

section figure figcaption {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px white;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
}

section figure:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

section figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200/1E5799/ffffff" alt="FPO">
    <figcaption>Text that should fade in</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```